# C#: How can I cut a String based on a Value?

Tags: c#, string

I have this string:

```
value1*value2*value3*value4
```

How would cut the String in multiple Strings?

```
string1 = value1;
string2 = value2;
etc...
```

My way (and probably not a very good way):
I take an array with all the indexes of the "*" character and after that, I call the subString method to get what I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cut a string variable into more?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471735/how-to-cut-a-string-variable-into-more)

Answer (score 3):

```
string valueString = "value1*value2*value3*value4";
var strings = valueString.Split('*');
string string1 = strings[0];
string string2 = strings[1];
...
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

simply :

```
 string[] parts = myString.Split("*");
```

parts will be an array of string (`string[]`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string string1 = "value1*value2*value3*value4";
var myStrings = string1.Split('*');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "value1*value2*value3*value4";
string[] array = s.Split('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the Split() method of the String-Object like so:

```
String temp = "value1*value2*value3*value4";
var result = temp.Split(new char[] {'*'});
```

The result variable is a string[] with the four values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shine in society, you can also use dynamic code :

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class DynamicParts : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
    {
        private string[] m_Values;

        public DynamicParts(string values)
        {
            this.m_Values = values.Split('*');
        }
        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            var index = Convert.ToInt32(binder.Name.Replace("Value", ""));
            result = m_Values[index - 1];
            return true;
        }


        public static void Main()
        {

            dynamic d = new DynamicParts("value1*value2*value3*value4");

            Console.WriteLine(d.Value1);
            Console.WriteLine(d.Value2);
            Console.WriteLine(d.Value3);
            Console.WriteLine(d.Value4);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```